# Cross platform grab web source C++

Tags: c++, http

I'm looking to grab the source of a webpage and add it to a string, all the guides I see though use curl or winsockets and I need this to be cross-compatible and use C++ only (No external libraries)

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Comment: C++'s standard libraries offer no such feature.

Comment: This would require cross-platform socket IO first which isn't available to begin with. You can start writing a small wrapper for a subset of unix/windows sockets and then implement a small subset of HTTP1 on top of that.

Comment: Use the cURL lib and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check `boost::asio`. It offers cross-platform networking, which will cover TCP/IP. `boost` is not a standard library, but it's *de facto* second standard C++ library. BTW, a lot of `boost` stuff ends up in `std`.

Next thing is HTTP client. Unfortunately, standard C++ library doesn't have HTTP client, but a basic, partial implementation of the protocol is simple enough that you can try to roll your own - you'll probably need only GET request. Try sending GET request over telnet, by typing it manually - you'll see it's very simple.

If SSL/TLS or a complete HTTP support is required, you may be forced to use a 3rd party library, because implementing them is a more than a challenging task.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ only without an external library? No such thing.

Qt is fairly cross platform, supporting Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android, iOS and a bunch of other more exotic platforms, plus embedded.

Qt 4 had a dedicated `QHttp` class, but it got deprecated and removed in Qt 5. With Qt 5 you will have to use the `QNetworkAccessManager` class:

A simple download off the network could be accomplished with:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
```

True, Qt 5 is a big framework, hardly justified for the purpose of that single task, but on the other hand, it is very powerful, very portable application development framework, so odds are it may come in handy in other aspects as well.